# Is it possible to set Cell background color per section?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to set the cell background color based on the section number but it's not working quite right. Cell colors change and are wrong as I scroll back and forth. I'm trying to do it using a color variable that is set in `willDisplayHeaderView` and is then used in `willDisplayCell`. Here's the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view     forSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if(section % 2 == 0){
        self.currentCellColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:(199/255.0) green:(214/255.0) blue:(156/255.0) alpha:1];
    }
    else{
        self.currentCellColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(242/255.0) green:(245/255.0) blue:(232/255.0) alpha:1];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = self.currentCellColor;
}
```

Also sections aren't vital to this piece of functionality so if anyone has a better/easier way of achieving this in one big section then feel free to suggest it. I just need to change the color every 4 rows.

Comment: did you tried this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.?

Comment: instead of in `willDisplayCell:`.? Or in conjunction with? Or something else? I tried setting it there too but it still messes up on scrolling.

Comment: insted of `willDisplayCell` and `willDisplayHeaderView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
    ....

    if (indexPath.section % 2) {    
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }

    return cell;  
}
```

Comment: Didn't realise I could get the section from indexPath, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it were me i would have a different cell identifier for each section and then set that cells color in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`  That way when scrolling and the tableView is reusing your cells you can be sure that it wont grab one that is the wrong color.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    ....

    if(indexPath.section % 2 == 0){
        self.currentCellColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:(199/255.0) green:(214/255.0) blue:(156/255.0) alpha:1];
    }
    else{
        self.currentCellColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(242/255.0) green:(245/255.0) blue:(232/255.0) alpha:1];
    }
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = self.currentCellColor;

    ....
    return cell;  
}
```